# It won't recognize the "intQuantity" value when typing a number , just assumes its ALL true =/

Tags: javascript

```
<script ="javscript"/>

function checkQuantity()
{

function noCharge(intQuantity){
  if (intQuantity > 100) {
    return true;
  }

  if (intQuantity < 100) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

checkQuantity=parseInt(prompt("Please enter the quantity of light bulbs",""))
if ((intQuantity)==true)
{
    alert("Your light bulbs will arrive shortly. There is NO delivery charge")
}
else if ((intQuantity)==false)
{
    alert("Your light bulbs will arrive shortly. There will be a  delivery charge of £5.99")
}
else
{
    alert("Please enter an amount")
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't "javscript" be "javascript" ?

Comment: Thanks for noticing that , I apologise

Comment: It says intQuantity is undefined as well =/

Comment: is this an actual copy of your exact code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code had some bugs.

Check this [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xuyev/)

```
function checkQuantity() {

    function noCharge(intQuantity) {
        if (intQuantity > 100) {
            return true;
        }

        if (intQuantity < 100) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    var amount = noCharge(parseInt(prompt("Please enter the quantity of light bulbs", "")));
    if (amount == true) {
        alert("Your light bulbs will arrive shortly. There is NO delivery charge")
    }
    else if (amount == false) {
        alert("Your light bulbs will arrive shortly. There will be a  delivery charge of £5.99")
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter an amount")
    }
}

checkQuantity();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious problems (well, two things collaborating to cause the same bug):

- You're never calling `noCharge`.  Rather than `if ((intQuantity) == true)`, you should be saying `if (noCharge(intQuantity) == true)` (or, better, `if (noCharge(intQuantity))`...see below).
- `(intQuantity)` will be truthy as long as it's not `false`, `null`, `undefined`, or 0.  In your case, that's the vast majority of the time.

And a couple of style notes:

- If you're returning a boolean, you don't really have to compare it to anything.  Instead of saying `if (noCharge(intQuantity) == true`, you could just say `if (noCharge(intQuantity))`.  To see if something's false, use the `!` operator, like `if (!noCharge(intQuantity))`.
- You also don't have to compare twice.  A boolean is either true or false.  The `else if...` part could be replaced with an `else`, and you could be rid of the third section altogether.
- Your rules in `noCharge` are more complicated than they have to be.  The current function returns true if, and only if, the quantity is at least 100.  Since `>=` covers that, you could reduce the code to one line: `return (intQuantity >= 100)`.
- Hungarian notation is dead.  Let it rest in peace.

With all that fixed:

```
 function checkQuantity() {
    function noCharge(quantity) {
        return (quantity >= 100);
    }

    var quantity = parseInt(prompt("Quantity:", ""));
    if (noCharge(quantity)) {
        alert("No delivery charge");
    } else {
        alert("Delivery charge of $5.99");
    }
}
```

Personally i wouldn't even bother with a function for checking whether something is at least 100...but i can see a use for it if the rules ever get more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very very much , You don't know how I appreciate this